# Read datafile with python to an array

Tags: python

This question is totally simple, but i don't get it done since hours: I got a datafile, that contains two columns of data, separated by an tab. I want to read and process them with python. `allData` contains the data, but how can i access parts of it?

```
with open( "file.txt", "r" ) as mergeData:
    allData = mergeData.read()

print allData
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most flexible way would be to use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open("file.txt", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")
    allData = list(reader)
```

Note that all the elements will be strings. If you want to convert, say, the first column to an `int` and the second column to a `float`, you could do something like

```
    allData = [(int(first), float(second)) for first,second in reader]
```

To split it up into two lists of floats, one for each column, use `zip()` together with the tuple unpacking operator (`*`):

```
    first, second = zip(*((float(x), float(y)) for x,y in reader))
```

Comment: This works so far just fine. For my understanding: Now everything is in the allData file. How can i split my data up into two files of floats?

Comment: `allData` is a list, not a file. At which point do you want to split that?

Comment: sure, you're right, its a list. I want two lists, each containing one column.

Comment: @user2003965: OK, that's a bit more complicated. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple:

```
with open( "file.txt", "r" ) as mergeData:
     allData = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in mergeData]
```

`csv` module mentioned by @TimPietzcker is nice but doesn’t handle unicode.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the Python 3 `csv` module handles Unicode.

Answer (score -1):

The[`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module is a good choice for reading in files of delimited data fields. The following creates a list of lists, and each one will contain the data read from the corresponding column in the data file. It can also easily be adapted to any number of columns of data:

```
import csv

NUM_COLS = 2
columns = [[] for _ in range(NUM_COLS)]
with open("datafile.txt", "rb") as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t"):
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(col)

for col in columns:
    print col
```

Sample tab-delimited input file:

```
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8
```

Output produced:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Answer (score -2):

why not:

```
fp = open("file.txt","r")
mylist = fp.readlines()   # get list of lines.
fp.close()  # i forgot that line [EDIT]
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = mylist[i].strip()   #get rid of ' ' and '\n' and such
    mylist[i] = mylist[i].split('separator') # splits line into list of elements in the line
```

mylist should then be a 2D array / list of your lines and single elements in each line.
separator should then be swapped with the char or string that separates your line elements.

Comment: This does not work (look at the `.strip()` line...) and is quite unpythonic and inefficient.

Comment: @ Tim: yeah sry, I am currently programming c++, so there come the ';' from^^. But why shall that be unpythonic, if uses the variable type lists which is typically to python? And it is also more basic than using a libary for that simple task.

Comment: 1. File object is iterable so it can be used instead of `mylist` 2. Lists are iterable too so you don't need indexes 3. If you really need indexes most of the time `enumarate` is cleaner if not more effective.

Comment: It's still wrong (I didn't even notice the `;`s). Strings are immutable. Building a list of strings first, then chopping that into a list of a list of strings is very slow and memory-inefficient. Plus the problems outlined by @zero323.

Comment: Don't forget about `split('separator')`.

Comment: @Martin: I disagree that "varialbe type lists" are Pythonic—in fact, I don't think it's good practice regardless of the language to use the same variable for data of different types, unless it's an absolute must for efficiency or smth—just because you can [in Python] doesn't mean you should. Furthermore, making the same `list` instance contain items of 2 or different types at the same time has even less to do with Pythonic'ness.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I typed that now and everything worked fine. In the line you mentioned i forgot mylist[i] = mylist[i].strip(), because otherwise .strip() changes will not be saved but the whole think works and does its jop

Comment: @ErikAllik: If you know what you do (and as programmer you should) you could use the benefit of python, that you are able to store different types of variables in a string. Of course you should then implement a test if each variable has the right type (if not there would be a users fault) but why should every tutorial tell you about that if it is "not good style"

Comment: @Martin: Because it most definitely isn't good style, except in cases that I've outlined—it often leads to hard-to-reason-about spaghetti, and it's hard to determine when it will and when it won't, so always better to stay clean of such code; besides, there's always a better way that is just as efficient; and I can't say your solution is particularly efficient even.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Might you possible also tell my WHY my solution is inefficient, so that I can improve my obviously bad style? I don't like to get told your style is bad or your performance is not good without a reason or a shown better way, which should be at minimum supplied, please

Comment: @Martin: Needless and repeated indexing as well as assignment into the array; compare to `mylist = [x.strip().split('...') for x in mylist]`.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Even better: Replace *the entire solution* with the following: `with open("file.txt") as fp: mylist = [x.strip().split('...') for x in fp]`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: yes, clearly—nothing iterated twice nor read in memory twice, and just one `list` created :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: But doesn't python split that short form up into my form. Isn't that just a compact writing (which seems to me not really clear)? Why does that save resources?

Comment: No, not at all. @ErikAllik and I already mentioned what's inefficient in the comments. You build a list, then change each element from a string into a different string, then change each element from a string into a new list - when you could have built the list in the correct format right from the start (which is what the list comprehension is doing).

Comment: @Martin: so I've done some profiling, at it turns out that in the case of small data files, the list-comprehension syntax is about 0-20% more efficient, however, in the case of large inputs, your code is significantly slower, especially in real life situations where you want to iterate over the data that's being read in. For a better understanding of why, I strongly suggest the classic http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/ ... the code I used for the profiling is here: https://gist.github.com/eallik/6762483